# how can I checkout the svn code of all maven child projects by only checkout the maven parent project?

Tags: maven, svn, bamboo

I am struggling too much to solve the problem which is given in bamboo logs

**[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project mainproject: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.sample:mainproject:war:0.5.022: Failure to find  com.sample.project1:project1:jar:1.0 in http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-release-local was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of oss-jfrog-artifactory has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]**

Comment: The error message shows that you need to delete this folder from the local repository and rerun the build.

Comment: thanks khmarbaise for suggestion !!

Comment: Actually I want to ask Is there any way to checkout the child project by checkout only parent one? I don't want to checkout manually my child projects.

Comment: Where is the problem to do either via SVN a `svn checkout URL/trunk` or a via Git a `git clone URL`? I don't see the problem? Bamboo by the way can simply checkout the whole tree so you have a CI solution so this should never be a problem....check the configuration in bamboo to do the checkout....Are we talking about a multi module build ?

Comment: yes, we are talking about multi module project,there are 2 other module in my main project and how to checkout all the code base by the checking out the parent one? I am using maven.

Comment: If you run in bamboo let checkout the submodule by bamboo ? I don't get what exactly the problem is. Haven't you configured to let SVN ? checkout recursively ?